# Voltage drop across PMOS (power mux circuit with two load switches)

Tags: transistors, pmos

I'm trying to build a power multiplexer (with two load switches made with pmos transistors). When 3V3 not present, it will use 1V8. I built this circuit but it drops the voltage to 2.6V (when 3V3 is present) and 1.12V (when only 1V8 is present).

[image: power multiplexer circuit]

I have tried NMOS and PMOS transistors but when I connect load to Source of transistor they drop the voltage.

How can I make this work properly? I want no voltage drop. I'm not sure this is the best way to make a power mux. If you have other suggestions please write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have drain and source connections swapped: -

[image]

You also need to ensure that when they are properly connected that 3.3 (and 1.8) volts is enough voltage to properly activate the MOSFETs. Given that your circuit does not contain anything other than a generic part name, I can't advise further.

Comment: _"3.3 (and 1.8) volts is enough voltage to properly activate the MOSFETs"_

Comment: solved the issue! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The PMOS transistors have their Drain and Source swapped.
So they conduct via the intrinsic diodes which explains the voltage drop.